# Detect each LED of LED array in real time video frames with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an array composed of LEDs whose size is 64*64. Every LED can light up in various colors and change its color very quickly. My ultimate goal is : for every frame received by a webcam, I want to be able to  "extract" the array of leds from the frame and store the color code of each led in an array of integers in the computer.

So I guess that what I will need is first a way to identify the LEDs array on an image. Then a way to individually Identify every LED of the array. And finally, a way to extract the color code of the LED (but that really looks like the easy part).

I am using C++ and OpenCV. Can you provide me some guideliness, functions that would be useful, or even simply ideas ? I'm quite a beginner with OpenCV, I only realized one project consisting in improving the snake contour algorithm for detecting contours on a image. So I know at least the basics of OpenCV.

Comment: Hi there! I'm looking for something very similar, did you find a solution? Unfortunately, the link in the answer below is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your task is similar to reading colors of rubik's cube edge.

You can find good approach here: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~andrejk/525project/

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey. I agree, that looks very close to what I'm trying to achieve.